# Empty Application, missing Properties and References folder?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-4.0

I just started out with ASP.NET. I am currently following a tutorial which started out by creating an `ASP.NET Empty Web Application`. All i have, that is somewhat similar, is `ASP.NET Empty Website`.

But that project template only supplies a `web.config` file with hardly anything in it and that's about it. But in the tutorial it shows that his project has a `Properties` and a `References` folder. And probably a more complete `web.config` aswell.

So what can i do best? Is there a way to add the `Properties` and `References` folder someway? And what about the incomplete `web.config`? This is the only stuff that is in there:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Or am i better of by starting with a `ASP.NET Web Forms Site` and then delete all the files i don't need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between Websites and Applications (=> [What's the difference between a web site and a web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694922/whats-the-difference-between-a-web-site-and-a-web-application)).
Open `File > New > Project` (`Ctrl + Shift + N`) and select the `ASP.NET Empty Web Application` from there.