# Distinguish Web application and website using response/request Headers

Tags: c#, web-applications, web, response, httpresponse

I am stuck in a situation where i have a bunch of urls and i have to distinguish them based on whether they belongs to website or webapp.

I tried to look at Response Header from the request and discovered that i can use **server field & powered By** field to check it.

But for most of the requests they are disabled so is there any other way to distinguish webapps from websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to identify that website id webapp or website on basis of user agent or some other property. its just term, here other question which might suite you - [What's the difference between a web site and a web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694922/whats-the-difference-between-a-web-site-and-a-web-application)