# Difference between website and web application?

Tags: php, web-applications, web

I really wonder with website and web application ? what is different between two of this ? And what is the advantage and disadvantage of this ?

everyone can you explain me more ?

thank for your supported !!!

Comment: Have you read this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694922/whats-the-difference-between-a-web-site-and-a-web-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is simple difference.

A website shows static or dynamic data that is predominantly sent from the server to the user only, whereas a web application serves dynamic data with full two way interaction.

A website shows essentially the same data. Some of it may be dynamic (e.g. CNN or BBC website), but it is generally a one way affair - you are a consumer only.

A web application is two way; you see data that is not only dynamic but often also specific to you. You can work with this data through the web application to publish new content or send meaningful requests back to the server or through the server to third parties (including other users). Examples include:

- a stock/share dealing application with real time price data and account, allowing you to deal in real-time.
- a photo editing application.
- a wedding wish list generator, shareable with your guests
- a web game with a persistent world

A wordpress site's publishing interface (where you write blog posts and generally manage the site) is a web application but the blog itself is not.
Youtube after you log in (so you can post comments or videos).

What is a website is generally accepted, but what is and is not a web application is a bit of a grey area; I would argue that Google maps is not a web application (its a dynamic web page with search and filtering), whereas Google mail is a true web application and so is much of social media.

Comment: @xmike thanks for editing and making it more useful .