# Is there a difference between a Java web app and Java website?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, web

Does a Java website and Java web app means the same thing? Or a webapp is actually an application which is served by java based server which is different than a website that opens in browser ? This is confusing, I am not experienced in this field, please bear with my ignorance.

Comment: Duplicate [What's the difference between a web site and a web application?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8694922/2764279)

Comment: Duplicate
try these, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694922/whats-the-difference-between-a-web-site-and-a-web-application
and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389925/difference-between-website-and-webapplication

Comment: the first  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694922/whats-the-difference-between-a-web-site-and-a-web-application) helped

Comment: @AnkitLamba  but what really a java web app is, a servlet?